# Xcode 7.3.1. My activity indicator keeps on spinning

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview, xcode7.3

I already checked the behavior on activity indicator view setting and coded it on a view controller..But still it keeps on spinning...What would be the problem?

I added this

```
@IBOutlet var Loadebest: UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

and this

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(_ : UIWebView) {
    Loadebest.startAnimating()
    NSLog("Webview is working")
}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView) {
    Loadebest.stopAnimating()
    NSLog("Webview stopped working")
}
```

But nothing happens...what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you set `hidesWhenStopped` to `true`?

Comment: Try stopping it in the main thread? Update UI **ON** the main thread, remember?

Comment: Hi @njuri, I'm using swift and checked everything, but nothing happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in storyboard, you have given delegate to webview.
If you haven't given delegate to webview then `webViewDidFinishLoad` will not call and it will not hide spinner.

Comment: Good, Have a happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView) {
  NSLog("Webview stopped working")
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.Loadebest.stopAnimating()
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property "hides when stopped" of the activity indicator.

You can do this either using the storyboard, there should be a small checkbox that enable this property in the inspector.

Or in objective C-

```
Loadebest.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is that method trigger more than one time. 
Replace your code with this one:

```
 private var webViewsload = 0

 func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

    self.navigationItem.title = LangData.get("WEB_VIEW_LOADING")
    webViewsload += 1
    self.updateButtons()

}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    webViewsload -= 1;
    activitiIndicator.stopAnimating()


    if (webViewsload == 0) {
        self.navigationItem.title = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.title");
    }
    self.updateButtons()


}
```

Hope this help.